# sudo error - "Structure needs cleaning"

Tags: sudo

On my Pi Zero, if I issue a `sudo su` I get the following:

```
$ sudo su
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: Structure needs cleaning
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: This usually indicates file system corruption.

Answer (score 5):

"Structure needs cleaning" has happened on my pi's external drives, and I've fixed it with:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
```

The "-y" flag instructs fsck to automatically fix any errors.

More info here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck

Comment: You should do a block level backup and backup any important files first, as this is a potentially destructive action.

Comment: Thanks, as this is happening on my Raspbian boot SD Card I'll put it in an adapter and back it up on another Linux system before then issuing the fsck against the SD Card.

Comment: @SteveRobillard. DD if=/dev/sda1 of=/home/user/backup/defective.sdcard.image.sda1.iso bs=8M status=progress   Is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 3):

The `fsck` worked. I had to put the micrSD card into an adapter and load it into the SD Card socket of a Linux laptop.

There were two partitions on the card, `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdb2`, so I ran the `umount` and `fsck` listed above on each, and all was well again.

Thanks for the help.